# What do I need to do this?

Tags: image, editor

I am new to coding and wanted to get some hands on practice with a project I have in mind. Here it is:

Let's say you have blank page and on the side of a screen you have several items you can choose to draw on the blank page. For example the background can be mountains, the ocean, a forest etc. On top of that you can place a house, a church or another selectable element. Whatever you like.

It is like a picture editor where you can put together a picture with different pre-given elements. Or like in video games where you can create your own character.

What would I need to build a web application for that kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

This link should get you started but it won't be the complete answer to your question - http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/08/how-to-use-html5s-drag-and-drop/

Essentially, you can achieve your image dragging and dropping using similar techniques. It will require a bit of Spike work from yourself, and looking into how HTML5 can handle drag and drop. I discovered this resource fairly quickly and I think the solution you want isn't as complicated as you may think, it just requires a bit of know-how regarding drag and drop operations within HTML5 :-)

Also, there may already be some JavaScript based API's that do this sort of thing easier but I'm not too aware - I suppose starting this way could be a great introduction for you and you may wish to expand once you've done some work for it :-)

Hope this helps you and your coding journey!

Comment: Literally just saw this demo - http://interactjs.io/ (click on the 'demo' tab) so that apparently would be a bit better - let me know what you go with and how the work pans out because it seems a fairly interesting idea :-D !

Comment: Hi and thanks for you reply,

I don't want to use drag and drop, I just want the effect that elements on the screen are interchangeable. And you can choose which element you want.

Example:
Your current picture is a forest with some rocks and a rabbit. But for whatever reason you don't like the rabbit so you click on the side menu and choose a deer instead. The rabbit is gone, the deer is now there and everything else stays the same.

This should work with JS, I guess?

Comment: Perhaps this then? - > [link](http://interestingwebs.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/change-image-onclick-with-javascript.html) (check the section titled, "Change image when user cick on image")

I guess, it's not the total solution to your problem, but again, a good start.

You give each element/image an ID and make that the showcase within the scene with onClick().

Sounds like an interesting concept for a web app and I think you'd definitely need a core set of defined requirements to help guide your SPIKE work :-)